# Flutter non-removable notifications

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wonder if there's a way to make a fixed notificatior or a non-removable notification using Flutter. I already seen "flutter_local_notifications" but I can't find a way to make something like this: [notification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XPnv.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To make notification non-removable ... just make ongoing: true in flutter_local_notifications package

```
AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = new AndroidNotificationDetails("channelId",
    notificationModel.title, notificationModel.body,
    ongoing: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As **ALL** notifications are removable in iOS (please correct me if I am wrong) its unlikely that you will find a flutter plugin that has this functionality. So your best bet is to implement this yourself using platform channels and use `Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;` to make the notifications un-removable.

Answer (score 0):

In notification object of android add this method
.setOngoing: true
This will make the notification un-removable.